# JMeter - Hitting specific endpoints based on user credentials via multiple CSV files

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, blazemeter, ruby-jmeter

My JMeter test:

- Iterate over a CSV file (logins.csv) with login credentials, and their unique identifier user a CsvDataSetConfig
- Sign in
- Based on the login credentials (unique identifier from logins.csv), identify and load a second file in the format of `<user_identifier>_invoices.csv` which then has the necessary path to view an invoice for that user.

Simplified test setup:

```
ThreadGroup
> CsvDataSetConfig - file: logins.csv, variables: user_identifier,email,password, sharing_mode: all threads
> `SignIn` TransactionController using email and password from above CSV file to login via series of HTTP Requests
> UserParameters - USER_IDENTIFIER,INVOICE_CSV_FOR_USER
> BeanShellSampler
  props.setProperty("USER_IDENTIFIER", vars.get("user_identifier"));
  props.setProperty("INVOICE_CSV_FOR_USER","${__P(USER_IDENTIFIER)}_invoices.csv");
> WhileController - condition: ${__javaScript("${invoice-id}" != "<EOF>",)}
  > CsvDataSetConfig - file: ${__P(INVOICE_CSV_FOR_USER,)}, variables: invoice-id, sharing_mode: current thread
  > `ViewInvoice` TransactionController with HTTP Request to url `../${invoice-id}`

# logins.csv
c7beaa99c6d99fa7754fc2213f9b17b8,foo@example.com,password321
9c8466bee65e39c9d3cf715e42933c3b,bar@example.com,password456

# c7beaa99c6d99fa7754fc2213f9b17b8_invoices.csv
f54eca1cbbba4a97c1dc459e0ba64970
0024f2cdf28dd7ebf3606988fd229afd

# 9c8466bee65e39c9d3cf715e42933c3b_invoices.csv
64f725fdeb2980b28bdf5e02076a55cd
60ac45a12ea3d6b59c2cb82f27da1722
```

**Problem:**

- In local JMeter, seeing requests to invoice urls being made with incorrect `invoice-id` for the business. So seems the parameters are not being treat correctly between threads.
- In BlazeMeter, seeing the content of the while controller never being hit.

I've tried loop controllers, having 50 rows per _invoices.csv file, but not got anywhere with that either. I also originally started off with 
User Defined Variables rather than User Parameters, but the latter seems to be what I should be using for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Threads are running at the same time and sharing JMeter properties.

In your test plan each thread sets the property `USER_IDENTIFIER`. So this and other property can/will be overriden by different thread(s) and create inconsistency.

I suggest you save (and get) in variables which aren't shared by threads:

```
 vars.put("USER_IDENTIFIER", vars.get("user_identifier"));

 vars.put("INVOICE_CSV_FOR_USER"," ${USER_IDENTIFIER}_invoices.csv");
```

Also about beanshell, JMeter advice to [change to JSR223](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

> Since JMeter 3.1, we advise switching from BeanShell to JSR223 Test Elements (see JSR223 section below for more details), and switching from __Beanshell function to __groovy function.